# Summation by parts with only one variable

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

I have a question about summation by parts:
I am supposed to show that
$\sum_{j=1}^{n}(v_j^m)(v_{j-1}^m-2v_j^m+v_{j+1}^m)=-\sum_{j=1}^{n}(v_{j+1}^m-v_j^m)^2$
where m is dependent on time.
I am given that $v_0^m=v_{n+1}^m=0$ and that I might use summation by parts which is given in the following way: $\sum_{j=0}^{n}(y_{j+1}-y_j)z_j=y_{n+1}z{n+1}-y_0z_0-\sum_{j=0}^{n}(z_{j+1}-z_j)y_{j+1}$. I do not understand how I can use this summation by parts formula when I only have the variable of v, while there are two variables in the formula, so I do not manage to prove that the first equation is true.

Comment: If $n=1$, the formula you are trying to prove becomes $-v_1^{2m}=-2v_1^{2m}$, so I'd suggest seeing whether there's a mistake in the formula.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Then I must have done something wrong in my derivation. I have now written the original expression that was supposed to be proven.

Comment: I think you still get nonsense when $n=1$.

Comment: The m-value in $v_j^m$ is only indicating what time the value is at. It does not mean that it is raised to the m-power. The expression above is the same as in my book.

Comment: On the left, I get $-2(v_1^m)^2$. On the right, I get $-(v_1^m)^2$. What do you get, when you put in $n=1$?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. When I let n=1 I get the following when the expression is multiplied out: $v_1^m v_2^m -2(v_1^m)^2=-(v_2^m)^2 +2v_1^mv_2^m - (v_1^m)^2$, which is the same as:  $(v_1^m)^2=-(v_2^m)^2+v_1^m v_2^m$

Comment: But when $n=1$, $v_2^m$ is zero.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Then I get the same answer as you did.

Comment: I still do not manage to show how the above equation can be proven. Does anyone understand how the summation by parts formula can be used in this situation, when we only have v (and not two different variables like y and z?)

Comment: We have established that the equation is FALSE. That is why no one will ever manage to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

First, $m$ is independant from the sum, so I will simply neglect it. Let
$$z_j=v_j$$
$$y_{j+1}=v_{j+1}-v_j$$
$$y_j=v_j-v_{j-1}.$$
Then,
$$\sum_{j=1}^n v_j (v_{j-1}-2v_j+v_{j+1})
=\sum_{j=1}^n \left((v_{j+1}-v_j)-(v_j-v_{j-1})\right)v_j
=\sum_{j=1}^n (y_{j+1}-y_j)z_j$$
Applying the formula, and accouting for the boundary conditions $v_0=v_{n+1}=0$, gives
$$\sum_{j=1}^n (y_{j+1}-y_j)z_j
=-\sum_{j=1}^n (z_{j+1}-z_j)y_{j+1}
=-\sum_{j=1}^n (v_{j+1}-v_j)(v_{j+1}-v_j)
=-\sum_{j=1}^n (v_{j+1}-v_j)^2.$$